# XlsxWriter usage on adding row

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

Anyone has the experience on working with library XlsxWriter?
I have a databrick notebook and i have a panda dataframe would like to write to xls using XlsxWriter

COl1   COL2
A B
C   D

I would like to add one more row on the top of the excel tables. and the excel look like the following:

TITLE
COL1   COL2
A B
C D

means adding a row at the top. Anyone has done this before ?

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Comment: anyhas the idea ?